# Calling a java function with an optionally null argument from clojure

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am trying to figure out how to use LWJGL3 directly from clojure. The only stumbling block I found so far is a function that sometimes requires an argument to be `null`, but it's type is `long` in the fingerprint.
The specific function in question is `glfwCreateWindow​` from the `org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW` class.
The last two arguments are `long`, but they should be `null` when using windowed mode, for the first one, or not sharing the gl context, for the second one.
The problem is interop calls check the fingerprint of the function and see it should be a `long`, so passing `nil` results in an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I've looked all around, but nobody seems to have addressed this particular problem. It's not about nil-punning, since the argument *should* sometimes be nil.

This is my code that already works: https://gist.github.com/Efimero/2c0af4ae3aeaf2c85136aa06ff077919

But it only works because the default zero values are fine for my setup, but they're not abstract.

When I pass `nil` I want the function to be called normally, but I get an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make sense.  A `long` cannot be null anywhere.  It seems that this is a miscommunication in the documentation, where the wrapped C or C++ library leaks through.

I'd strongly guess that passing `0` where the documentation says `NULL` is correct.

Comment: That's what I thought, but check it out yourself: https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwCreateWindow(int,int,java.nio.ByteBuffer,long,long)
You use null to not share the context.

Comment: in C, 0 == NULL (actually there’s subtlety here but wtf). I agree that this doc is just the underlying C poking through. There is no way to pass null for an unboxed long.